# How to collapse a panel?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've been doing a lot of research on this and can't find a good solution. Basically, I have a panel in my app `(Panel 2)` and would like to **collapse it** to the left when the button is clicked and if the button gets clicked again then **expand it** to the right.

**Here's my working Code:** [**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/k5Wn7sjVt3FozIqogeK7?p=preview)

---

```
  <div fxFlex fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between stretch" style="background-color:green;">
      <div fxFlex [fxShow]="explorerShow"  style="background-color:white;">        
 <div  (click)="toggleDirection()" > <img src="../../../assets/images/button1.png" alt="Button" style = 'float: right'>
 </div>
      Panel 2
 </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried varying the Flex attribute when the button is clicked? flex: 10 0 10;

Comment: Just have a classA where the %grow and %shrink for the represent expanded and classB where middle div is shrunk. onClick change the classNames. Might have to also change the DIV contents with something like a zIndex change on the shrunk DIV so it doesn't look silly.

Comment: use CSS grid over flexbox. ...my 2 cents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `fxHide` and `[fxShow]="expand"` on **Panel 2** element

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="content" fxLayout="row" fxFlexFill>

      <div class="sec1" fxFlex="20%" fxHide [fxShow]="expand">
          SIDEBAR
      </div>
      <div class="sec2" fxFlex="100%">
          BODY
      </div>
  </div>

  <button (click)="expand = !expand">Toggle Sidebar</button>

</div>
```

Here is a working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-flex-layout-seed-ymh5pt?file=app%2Ftest.component.ts) | [your plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/QeHWlNXSdtmSZNuk9gm8?p=preview)

**UPDATE:** Here is a [stackblitz with animation](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-flex-layout-seed-phmuqf?file=app/test.component.css)